# How to correctly interpret the cursor's position?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, insert-mode, cursor

I'm having trouble understanding the cursor in the context of Vim commands, e.g. insertion, deletion, movement, etc:

- When the cursor is hovering over a character and I want to delete until the end of the line, or to the beginning of the line, should I expect that the character it's pointing to will also be deleted?
- When I enter `insert` mode, should I expect that the insertion will take place before or after the current character?
- What about when pasting with `p`?

I'm not looking for specific answers to these examples, I'm looking for a general explanation or rules to understand the "current position" so I don't keep executing commands that end up being off by 1 character because I misinterpreted it.  In GUI editors the caret usually sits between instead of on top of characters, so it's never been a source of confusion.

Comment: You said you don't want specific answer but that's what you should be looking for: Deleting until the end of the line see [`:h D`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#D) and you'll read `Delete the characters under the cursor until the end of the line`, entering insert mode if you use `a` you **a**ppend text after the cursor if you use `i` you **i**nsert text before the cursor, if you read [`:h p`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#p) and scroll to `:h P` you'll see that one command is 'paste before' and the other 'paste after'... Your best option is to read the doc

Comment: Note that Vim allows you to configure the shape of the cursor fairly extensively (see `:help guicursor`). I wouldn't *recommend* that you change it to be a vertical-bar type cursor when in normal mode (It might help you interpret motions, but I think it would make commands like `a` and `p` confusing), but you *can*.

Comment: @statox sure, but I assumed there was a general principle / rhyme / reason to why the commands worked the way they did, and that it would be consistent across these commands and commands I haven't yet encountered where I can anticipate behavior.  Ingo Karkat's answer shed some light in this respect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right mental model is that the cursor is *before* the current character. So, any `{motion}` that moves to the right (e.g. `$`, `w`) includes the character under the cursor, whereas any motion to the left (e.g. `^`) excludes it.

Likewise, `i` inserts before the current character, whereas `a` appends after it. Same for pasting with `P` (before) / `p` (after).